# How to Django queryset annotate True when all BooleanField of related objects are True else False?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate, django-related-manager

I have a model who looks like this :

```py
class Test(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class TestVersion(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey('Test', models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    validation_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    validation_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    validation_3 = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    validation_4 = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
```

Sometimes i have like hundreds of `TestVersion` linked to a `Test`.

And I want something like :

```py
user_test = Test.objects.filter(
    user=request.user
).annotate(
    number_of_test=Count('testversion', distinct=True),
    all_validation_1="True or False ?", # if all testversion_set.all() of the current test are True, return True else False.
    all_validation_2="True or False ?", # same
    all_validation_3="True or False ?", # same
    all_validation_4="True or False ?", # same
).distinct()

# I Want for example :
test_1 = user_test.first()
test_1_validation_1 = test_1.testversion_set.all().count()
test_1_validation_1_true = test_1.testversion_set.filter(validation_1=True).count()
all_validation_1 = test_1_validation_1 == test_1_validation_true
test_1.all_validation_1 == all_validation_1 # True

# Or something like :
test_1 = user_test.first()
all_validation_1 = all(test_1.testversion_set.all().values_list('validation_1', flat=True))
test_1.all_validation_1 == all_validation_1 # True
```

I have not been able to find what techniques were used to achieve this level of accuracy with related objects in annotate method.

Any ideas ?

Thank's

**Update :** Thank's you [Sumithran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6562458/sumithran) for your answer.

But I don't want `all_validated` I want to manage `all_validation_1` next to `all_validation_2` for some check.

If I take example on your solution, it almost work with a little throwback that I don't understant :

```py
test = Test.objects.annotate(
    number_of_test=Count("testversion", distinct=True)
).annotate(
    all_validation_1=Case(
        When(Q(testversion__validation_1=True), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    ),
    all_validation_2=Case(
        When(Q(testversion__validation_2=True), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

But for some `Test` objects there is some duplication :

```py
test.filter(name='test_27')
>> <QuerySet [<Test: test_27>, <Test: test_27>]>
test.filter(name='test_27')[0] == test.filter(name='test_27')[1]
>> True
test.filter(name='test_27')[0].all_validation_1
>> True
test.filter(name='test_27')[1].all_validation_1
>> False
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: To avoid duplication use distinct() method in the queryset, I habe update the answer.

Comment: Sorry forget to precise that .distinct() don't do the tricks on Sqlite. Maybe on other database it could work ?

Comment: You can use .discinct() with SQLite, but if you want to use .distinct("some_filed_name") then you should use some other db like Postgre..

Comment: Yes sure, I tried .distinct() on SQLite but there are still duplicated objects, I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry you cant use .distinct() in this scenario, you should use distinct("id") in order to solve this.. unfortunately this is not possible with SQLite, you have to switch the db, preferably PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ok, so you think there is no other solution for these kind of requests ? As soon as I have tested on another database, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Django's [Conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#the-conditional-expression-classes) in combination with the [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects).

Give this a try

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField, Count, Q

test = Test.objects.annotate(
    number_of_test=Count("testversion", distinct=True)
).annotate(
    all_validated=Case(
        When(
            Q(testversion__validation_1=True)
            & Q(testversion__validation_2=True)
            & Q(testversion__validation_3=True)
            & Q(testversion__validation_4=True),
            then=Value(True),
        ),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
).distinct()
```

if all of your test validations are True then the value of output filed `all_validated` will be True otherwise it be False

Answer (score 0):

I finally find an other answer :

```py
from test.models import Test, TestVersion
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, Exists, OuterRef, Value, BooleanField

test = Test.objects.filter(
    user=request.user
).annotate(
    number_of_test=Count("testversion", distinct=True),
    all_validation_1=Case(
        When(
            Exists(TestVersion.objects.filter(test=OuterRef('pk'), validation_1=False)), 
            then=Value(False)
        ),
        default=Value(True),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).distinct()
```

In this case :

```py
>> test.first().all_validation_1 == all(test.first().testversion_set.all().values_list('validation_1', flat=True))
True
```

So I just need to reiterate the same thing for validation_2, 3 and 4 and it should be ok.

But I think it will be a little bit fat code. Or it can be a good practice ?

Let me know before I check the answer.